# Question about a proposition on sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis

To define our terms: Let $\{ X_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A } $ be any collection and $X = \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} $. Let $\pi_{\alpha}: X \to X_{\alpha} $ be coordinate maps and let $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ be sigma algebras on $X_{\alpha} $. The product sigma algebra on $X$ is generated then by the  $\{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha} ) : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A\}$, and we denote it by $\bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $.

#### PROP:

Suppose $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ is generated by $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $, and let $\mathcal{F} = \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha} ) : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} \} $. Im trying to understand the proof to show $\bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $

The proof is as follows: Consider the collection $\mathcal{G} = \{ V \subset X_{\alpha} : \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(V) \in \sigma( \mathcal{F} ) \} $. I understand and have proved that this is a $\sigma-$algebra. What I don't understand is

Why does $\mathcal{G} $ contain $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $ and $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ ??

Comment: $\mathcal G$ contains $\mathcal E_\alpha$ by definition! Say $E_\alpha\in\mathcal E_\alpha$. The definition of $\mathcal F$ shows that $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)\in\mathcal F\subset\sigma(\mathcal F)$, so $E_\alpha\in\mathcal G$.

Comment: How do you know the elements of $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}$ are of the form $E_{\alpha} $?

Comment: ??? What does "of the form $E_\alpha$" mean?

Comment: You are taking an element $E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $, how do you know $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} = \{ E_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A \} $ ?

Comment: I don't know that. I never said or implied that. In fact the notation $\{E_\alpha\,:\,\alpha\in A\}$ doesn't quite make sense, since we haven't defined $E_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$.

Comment: I am confused. I don't understand why you say $E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha } $

Comment: You're confused about something very basic regarding sets, or variables, or names for variables or something. We're trying to show that $\mathcal E_\alpha\subset\mathcal G$. That means that every element of $\mathcal E_\alpha$ is an element of $\mathcal G$. So we choose an element of $\mathcal E_\alpha$ and show that it is an element of $\mathcal G$. I just  _named_ that element $E_\alpha$. I used that name just to emphasize that it was an element of $\mathcal E_\alpha$. The proof would be exactly the same if I'd started "Suppose $Q\in\mathcal E_\alpha$" and concluded "So $Q\in\mathcal G$".

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. Why don't you write this as an answer so I can award you the points for helping me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Last question, why does $\mathcal{F}$ contains also $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ ?

Comment: It doesn't. Assuming you meant $\mathcal G$ instead of $\mathcal F$, this is also immediate from the definitions. See answer. In general, what is $\sigma(A)$? It's the smallest sigma-algebra containing $A$. That means two things: (i) $\sigma(A)$ is a sigma-algebra containing $A$, (ii) If $\mathcal A$ is any sigma-algebra containing $A$ then $\sigma(A)\subset\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clear just from sorting through the definitions. Including every detail I can imagine, hoping to hit the one you're missing:

We want to show that $\mathcal E_\alpha\subset\mathcal G$. The *definition* of $A\subset B$ is that every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. So we assume that $E\in\mathcal E_\alpha$ and now we need to show that $E\in\mathcal G$.

The definition of $\mathcal F$ shows that $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal F$. Since $\mathcal F\subset\sigma(\mathcal F)$ this shows that $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E)\in\sigma(\mathcal F)$. Now the definition of $\mathcal G$ shows that $E\in\mathcal G$, which is what we needed to prove.

So $\mathcal E_\alpha\subset \mathcal G$. It follows that $\mathcal M_\alpha\subset \mathcal G$: We know that $\mathcal M_\alpha$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal E_\alpha$. This means that $\mathcal M_\alpha$ is the *smallest* sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal E_\alpha$. That says precisely that $\mathcal M_\alpha\subset\mathcal G$, since $\mathcal G$ is *a* sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal E_\alpha$.

Comment: perfect clear now. Thanks a lot!!